# The 'uvloop>=0.14.0' distribution was not found and is required by uvicorn

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, uvloop

I'm new at learning FastAPI, and I'm getting stuck at the very beginning. I keep getting the following error:

```
(venv) root@Xue:/home/proyectos/FastAPI# uvicorn main.py:app --reload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/uvicorn", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3237, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3266, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'uvloop>=0.14.0' distribution was not found and is required by uvicorn
```

this is my python code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {'Hello': 'World'}
```

I already try with `pip install -U uvloop pip, pip install uvloop==0.14.0` and no fix.

Comment: Check out that you may be using python 3.x, but installing libraries for python 2.x . Try using the command `pip3 install uvloop`

Comment: Thanks, bro didn't work with pip3 install uvloop but I tried with pip3 install uvicorn, and worked fine

Comment: @Xuerivera Good if you answer your own question and accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I tried running using the following command and this worked for me:

> python -m uvicorn main:app --reload

here the main is your file name

Answer (score 3):

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
```

and then install FastAPI using

```
pip install FastAPI[all]
```

Comment: `pip install "fastapi[all]"`

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem.
First, activate your venv:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Freeze and safe pip list in requirements:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Uninstall:

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
```

Deactivate:

```
rm -r venv/
```

After this you have to remake venv:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

And install all necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by installing my Python requirements outside of my virtualenv on my root python

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

`deactivate`

`pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`

Answer (score 0):

`pip install uvicorn` solved the issue for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).